# SerialPort.Parity = SerialParity.Even not working, UWP + Raspberry pi + Windows 10 IoT core + C#

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to send a string from my raspberry pi to PC through Serial port.

**Case 1:** My PC terminal settings : BD 9600, **None** Parity, 8 Databits, 1 Stop Bit and Raspberry Pi also configured for the same Settings and my string gets transmitted from Rpi to PC with out any problem.

**Case 2:** My PC terminal settings : BD 9600, **Even** Parity, 8 Databits, 1 Stop Bit and Raspberry Pi also configured for the same Settings and PC terminal received Garbage values.

**Case 3:** My PC terminal settings : BD 9600, **None** Parity, 8 Databits, 1 Stop Bit and Raspberry Pi configured for BD 9600, **Even** Parity, 8 Databits, 1 Stop Bit and my string gets transmitted from Rpi to PC with out any problem.

According to my understanding, In case 1 and Case 2, the string has to get transmitted and in case 3, PC terminal may receive garbage values.

I am using the following example [Serial UART Sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart).

Is this a known issue or am i missing something.
Please Guide.

Thank You

Comment: For **case 2**, you can try to set 7 Databits on PC terminal and other settings stay the same.

Comment: What's the difference between case 1 and case 3 ?

Comment: Hi thank u for responding, i will try out your solution..sorry case 3 i have edited, thank you for pointing it .actually in case 3 the Raspberry Pi is configured for BD 9600, Even Parity, 8 Databits, 1 Stop Bit

Comment: I tried changing the Case 2 data bit to 7 in PC as per your suggestion, but still receive garbage value. I have tried changing the pi and uart converter but still i am unable to isolate the problem area.

Comment: If my workaround isn't working for you, you may need to avoid using parity feature currently. I have reported this issue internally.

Comment: I am trying to communicate with my siemens servo v 90 series which only works with Even parity, so i can not avoid using parity feature.May be i ll wait and see if i can get any support to overcome this issue.thanks for your support, also please follow up on this issue from your end.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you could try to find out if there is an issue in your C# library (or underlaying dll) or the (USB-)device driver (for example CH340).

Check the port using the MODE command:

```
C:>mode COM3

Status for device COM3:
-----------------------
    Baud:            9600
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       7
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         OFF
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     ON
    RTS circuit:     ON
```

Configure the port using the MODE command and try if you can set parity manually:

```
C:>help mode
Configures system devices.

Serial port:       MODE COMm[:] [BAUD=b] [PARITY=p] [DATA=d] [STOP=s]
                                [to=on|off] [xon=on|off] [odsr=on|off]
                                [octs=on|off] [dtr=on|off|hs]
                                [rts=on|off|hs|tg] [idsr=on|off]
...
```

```
C:\>mode COM3 PARITY=E DATA=8

Status for device COM3:
----------------------
    Baud:            9600
    Parity:          Even
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         OFF
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     ON
    RTS circuit:     ON
```

**Note**:
There are two Parameters (**dcb.Parity** and **dcb.fParity**) that control the Parity settings and both Parameters must be set.